# Regex expression is not working correctly

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to find in a  string in which numbers are formatted as "4.97", but if they are smaller than 1, they are in the format .97, .80 etc. I want to find these kind of substrings in the String and replace them so that they would start with a 0.

It's working for the string

```
String str = "Rate is : .97";

Result : "Rate is : 0.97"
```

But not for the string:
    `String str = "Rate is : .97  . XXXXXXXXX do you want .  to perform another calculation . ";`

```
    String str = "Rate is : .97  . XXXXXXXXX do you want . 87 to perform another calculation . ";
    String pattern = "(.*\\D)(.\\d\\d.*)";
    System.out.println(str.matches("(.*\\D)(.\\d\\d.*)"));
    str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "$10$2");
```

Why is this  happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, the `.*` after the last `\\d` will match any character except a newline which will match the rest of the string.

You might do the replacement without a capturing group using a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` to check if what is on the left is not a non whitespace char.

```
(?<!\S)\.[0-9]
```

In the replacement use a zero followed by the full match.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4m7sKA/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/aJgJ0i)

```
String str = "Rate is : .97  . XXXXXXXXX do you want . 87 to perform another calculation . ";
String pattern = "(?<!\\S)\\.[0-9]";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "0$0"));
```

Output

```
Rate is : 0.97  . XXXXXXXXX do you want . 87 to perform another calculation .
```

---

If there should be a non digit before, you could make use of a positive lookbehind

```
(?<=\D)\.[0-9]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EI8M3q/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<=\\D)\\.[0-9]";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add some lazy matching to your regex.

`?` means it will attempt to match as few times as possible, in this case it's to only pick up the first number and not go onto the second.

```
^(.*?\D)(.\d\d.*?)
```

[You can see this regex work here, with a more complete explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/DsSTez/1)

I have also added the `^` start of string matcher so to make sure only one match it created and not repeated onto the second.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your regex pattern seems to be wrong. I think you can just use:

```
(\D)(\.\d+)
```

Find a character that is not a digit, followed by a dot and at least one digit.

Second, for replacing, you could use more low-level features, such as:

```
String str = "Rate is : .97  . XXXXXXXXX do you want . 87 to perform another calculation . ";

final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\D)(\\.\\d+)");
final Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
  str = m.replaceFirst(m.group(1) + "0" + m.group(2));
}

System.out.println(str);
```

But of course, this works too:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\D)(\\.\\d+)", "$10$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a positive lookahead so that way you also catch whitespaces between . and the number.

```
(.(?=.\d)|(\d+))+
```

would give you

[image]

Then in your code you can do whatever operation on group 1(blue) and group 2(red) as you wish.